# How to convert a lat long Earth position at a given time to J2000 inertial coordinate system coordinates

Tags: geometry

Given a Date object (i.e. a moment in time) and an Earth relative position (lat long and altitude), how does one derive the position expressed in J2000 celestial inertial coordinates?

Thanks!

Kerry Soileau

PS I managed to write my own function to convert an inertial vector to lat/long on a mean spherical Earth:

```
    geodetic[date_, vector_] := 
     Module[{costm, latitude, longitude, rad2degs = 180/Pi, 
       siderealTime = SiderealTime[{0, 0}, date], sintm, 
       vectorMagnitude = QuantityMagnitude[vector], xUnitVector, 
       yUnitVector, zUnitVector},
      sintm = Sin[siderealTime];
      costm = Cos[siderealTime];
      xUnitVector = {costm, sintm, 0};
      yUnitVector = {-sintm, costm, 0};
      zUnitVector = {0, 0, 1};
      latitude = 
       rad2degs*
        ArcTan[(vectorMagnitude.zUnitVector)/
          Sqrt[(vectorMagnitude.xUnitVector)^2 + \
    (vectorMagnitude.yUnitVector)^2]];
      longitude = 
       rad2degs*
  ArcTan[vectorMagnitude.xUnitVector,vectorMagnitude.yUnitVector];
      {latitude, longitude}
      ]
```

The inverse function is given by:

```
inertial[date_, radius_, latitude_, longitude_] := 
 Module[{costm, degs2rad = Pi/180, 
   siderealTime = SiderealTime[{0, 0}, date], sintm, xUnitVector, 
   yUnitVector, zUnitVector},
  sintm = Sin[siderealTime];
  costm = Cos[siderealTime];
  xUnitVector = {costm, sintm, 0};
  yUnitVector = {-sintm, costm, 0};
  zUnitVector = {0, 0, 1};
  radius (Cos[degs2rad*latitude] Cos[degs2rad*longitude] xUnitVector +
      Cos[degs2rad*latitude] Sin[degs2rad*longitude] yUnitVector + 
     Sin[degs2rad*latitude] zUnitVector)
  ]
```

Comment: For [reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130580/how-to-determine-satellite-position-in-j2000-from-latitude-longitude-and-distan).

Comment: Kerry, self-answers are encouraged in this forum. Please convert your edit to the question into your own answer!

Comment: I tried, but I encountered character limits that prevented it.